# while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) won't terminate?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, readline, reader

I'm writing some code in Java to scan through a .txt file. Each line in the file contains two tokens, and there's only about 7 rows of data.

My aim is to use the while loop to scan through each line, store the tokens in a HashMap, and when the scanner reaches the end of the document I want the while loop to terminate. Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        s = new Scanner(line);
        String fileName = s.next();
        String source = s.next();
        sourceMap.put(fileName, source);
    }
```

This is something I have done many times before, however there are now some issues with the while loop terminating. The while loop continues to operate even after the 'final' line has been read. When the scanners attempt to read tokens, a java.util.NoSuchElementException is returned.

From using the debugger I can see that the line immediately after the 'final' line of code is being read as: `""`

I believe this is an empty string, however I am unsure if this is different to a line being `null`. I attempted to add code for the condition `while (line != "")` however this did not result in the while loop being terminated.

Has anyone experienced similar issues before, and if so how did you overcome them?

EDIT: This has now been resolved. There was a line with an empty string after the 'final' line in the .txt file. The corrected code is as follows:

```
while ((line != null) && (!line.isEmpty())) {
        s = new Scanner(line);
        String fileName = s.next();
        String source = s.next();
        sourceMap.put(fileName, source);
        line = b.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: Does the file have a blank line at the end?  That would cause a `""` string read followed by a `null` string being read

Comment: Check the sourcefile for empty lines and if needed use String.equals("") or String.isEmpty() to check for empty Strings.

Comment: The empty string `""` is not the same as `null`. Also, checking if `line!=""` will not work reliably, because you need to use `equals` to compare strings. (Or `if (!line.isEmpty())` )

Comment: What is the type of `b`?

Comment: Please, share the exception trace and the file content.

Comment: The exception is: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at exam16_17_final.DataAnalysis.soundSourceFromURL(DataAnalysis.java:85)
 at exam16_17_final.ExamPart1.main(ExamPart1.java:12)

Comment: The NoSuchElement exception is only to be expected as you are trying to scan a token from an empty string. The problem is just that your file has an empty line at the end.